# Dynamic patch redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I tried various methods with mod_rewrite in htaccess but nothing works.
I need to redirect 301 dynamically for url from `https://somesite.net/cars/truck/123-volvo-truck.html`
to `https://somesite.net/cars/123-volvo-truck.html`

patches `cars`, `truck` need be dynamic.

I cant construct procedure for this. Thank You

```
Options All -ExecCGI -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://somesite.net/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)([0-9]+)(.*).html$ $1/$3.html [L] -- tried this last time
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does `https://somesite.net/cars/123-volvo-truck.html` show correct content when you visit it now?

Comment: No. Only 404 error give

Comment: Thats why i dont understant. I will try to understand htaccess syntax more deepest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this as your last redirect rule:

```sh
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/(\d+-.+\.html?)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! If you can , please explain me for what we need hooks. First: ^(  and last:  )  Thank you!